# How to read excel file by cells and transform it into matrix by python?

Tags: python, excel

For example,how can I read excel file by cells from A1 to C3 and transform them to matrix of 3*3.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your excel table as CSV (comma separated value) and if you open your csv file in noteped you will see your values in shape like this

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

then you can use python csv library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read and parse that information and finally to add it into some matrix. Something like this:

```
import csv

matrix = []

with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        x = []
        for el in row:
            x.append(el)
        matrix.append(x)

print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pandas` and `xlrd` to read from excel and transform it to a list.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("name.xls", header=None)
matrix = df.values.tolist()
```